Move arms into a direction using angles not working properly
I am using motionProxy.angleInterpolation(chain_id, angle_list, timeLists, True,_async=True) from http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/motion/control-joint.html#control-joint to move the arms toward a certain direction based on the angles of the joints. But as soon as the call to the mentioned function terminates, the arm slowly returns to its initial resting position, my question being to prevent it from returning to its initial resting position?
UPDATE:
motionProxy = ALProxy("ALMotion", "10.0.0.56", 9559)
motionProxy.setStiffnesses("LArm", 1.0)
motionProxy.setStiffnesses("RArm", 1.0)
angle_list=[[0.3], [0.2], [-0.9], [-0.5], [-0.9], [0.05]]
timeLists=[[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5]]
list_chain_id = ['RShoulderPitch', 'RShoulderRoll', 'RElbowYaw', 'RElbowRoll', 'RWristYaw', 'RHand']
motionProxy.angleInterpolation(list_chain_id, angle_list, timeLists, True)


pls check code update
